# supporting multi-tenant routes in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, multi-tenant

I'm experimenting setting up a multi-tenant solution in asp.net mvc 4 wherein you are able to specify tenant specific overrides to certain controllers if they require different functionality.

I'd like to have routes that are like

```
/{Controller}/{Action}/{Id}/
/{Tenant}/{Controller}/{Action}/{Id}
```

If the tenant isn't specified it should just match the first route.

I have tried

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Tenant",
                url: "{tenant}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { tenant = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

This works correctly for

- */* -> detected as the first route (correct!)
- */Home* -> detected as
  first route (correct!)
- */Home/Index* -> detected as first route
  (correct!)
- */Client1/Home/Index* - Client1 is detected as controller
  name (incorrect)

If I switch the routes around then the tenant route works but the base one does not.

What am I missing here, is it possible to achieve this?

*Note, I'd prefer to not have to specify a dummy tenant string in the route as I'll have to translate that back later on in a few places where I need to resolve tenant specific information.*

Comment: What is Tenant here? Is it parameter of Action?

Comment: tenant isnt a parameter of action, its just extra information I can use elsewhere in the mvc pipeline for resolving tenant specific dependencies and views etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use the library I wrote [here](http://www.siyamand.com/ASPNET-Several-Optional-Parameters-in-body-of-Urls). This lib allows you to define an alternative route, if the routes conflict. You must define the routes as follows:

```
var firstRoute = routes.MapReplaceableRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });    

var secoundRoute = routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Tenant",
            url: "{tenant}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { tenant = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
UrlParameter.Optional }, lookupParameters: new string[] {"tenant"}, lookupService: new LookupService());

firstRoute.AlternativeRoute  = secondRoute;
```

For lookupService, you just need an empty implementation of the IRouteValueLookupService.

Comment: looks promising will give it a go

Comment: The link to the code is broken. Does anyone have a copy?